# SmartEdit preview URL and Spartacus Context

Tags: spartacus-storefront

The Spartacus documentation says [here](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/smartedit-contract/#wcms-cockpit-preview-url-and-spartacus-context):

> The WCMS Cockpit Preview URL must match the default context for your Spartacus web site.
>
> For example, if you go to https://localhost:4200, you will see the default URL path (or context), such as https://localhost:4200/en/USD. The Preview URL (set in Backoffice) must match the default context uses, or errors will occur using SmartEdit. The default context installed by Spartacus Schematics is https://localhost:4200/en/USD.

We have a instance with the demo shop, when I go to the SmartEdit and check the request to the frontend the context is missing:

[image: SmartEdit]

Configuration for the preview URL:

[image: Preview URL]

The test shop was setup with the default configuration. Is maybe the documentation or the test shop data out of date?

Comment: The documentation is out of date. The preview url must match your app's url. When the SPA app launched in SmartEdit, SmartEdit sends the request with the preview url.

Comment: Did you find solution?